# Mysqld Crashes immediately on running on Windows 7...?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run MySql 5.1 on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit. I have downloaded the MSI installer from the MYSql website and installed it. The installation is successful, but the service does not start.

If I try to run MySql manually using the mysqld executable, it crashes immediately on running (error: mysqld.exe has stopped working).

Earlier mysql was running on the machine, but I had some problem with it (wasn't executing big queries) and installed it again which somehow broke the program. I had installed it to work as a service which started giving me this isse, and now it won't work even if  I don't install it as a service.

I have tried removing the mysql folder and re-installing. Is there somewhere else where Mysql saves configuration info or other data?

Has anyone else found this problem and solved it?

How can I find out why the process is failing to run?

Comment: You *may* be in DLL hell.  Can you get a stack trace?

Comment: How can I get a stack trace for mysqld?

Comment: Run `mysqld-debug --debug --standalone`.  When/if it crashes see if there's a way to obtain additional details from the "mysqld-debug has stopped working" window.  After the crash also look at the `mysqld.trace` file to see what went on immediately before the crash.

Comment: I don't know if you did this: If you copy from database a old XAMPP installation (/mysql/data folder) to new XAMPP installation, it can cause this error. Remove the old database which you copied and restart mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [Debugging a MySQL Server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/debugging-server.html) in your MySQL reference manual.

- download the `noinstall` (zip archive) version of MySQL corresponding exactly to the version that is already installed on your system
- extract the `.pdb` symbols files to your existing MySQL installation's `bin` directory
- [start Dr. Watson](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/making-windows-dumps.html)
- [start `mysqld-debug` in standalone mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/making-trace-files.html)
- capture the list of all moduled (i.e. loaded DLLs) with their full path from DrWatson
- capture the stack trace from DrWatson
- [examine the MySQL log files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/using-log-files.html) (including `mysqld.trace`) to see what went on immediately prior to the crash

Answer (score 2):

Or you can try and run the mysqld.exe as administrator.